# Code / function not executing properly don’t understand error code

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I’m just learning swift and can’t seem to figure out a problem.

I’ve tried changing the function text but nothing seems to be working

```
func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    a * b
}
```

> solution.swift:2:7: warning: result of operator '*' is unused
>       a * b
>       ~ ^ ~ solution.swift:3:1: error: missing return in a function expected to return 'Double' } ^

Comment: That should work in Swift 5.1. Are you using a lower Swift version?

Comment: This function's return type is Double so you should `return` a Double. Add `return a * b` to your function.

Comment: Hi yes. It’s part of an online coding challenge so I have no control over swift version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code uses the new feature introduced in Swift 5.1 - implicit returns from single expression functions. ([New features in Swift 5.1](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/182/whats-new-in-swift-5-1))

Make sure you are using Swift 5.1/Xcode 11. If you are not, you have to write `return`:

```
func multiply(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    return a * b
}
```

Comment: Wow.perfect. Thank you,